# Accessing Live Site Domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cant access the live domain for the Rails 3 application i created on my macbook. I can obviously access localhost:3000 for testing purposes, but when i log on to my live domain `http://truthpage.me` it sends the request and eventually times out. Doesnt work in any browser on my machine only. We are hosting the app with `heroku` if that makes any difference. Do any of you guys have a solution to why this doesnt work? thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Stacktrace ?  'heroku logs'

Comment: its just a "Sending request" in chrome, waiting, loading loading loading, and eventually the typical "Google chrome could not connect to truthpage.me" etc.

Comment: when that same "Google chrome could not connect error" comes up, the very old favicon we used prior for the site renders on the page. We haven't used this favicon in three or four months, yet it still renders with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try flushing your DNS cache:

```
 $> dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Also, ensure there's nothing causing an unintentional redirection in your hosts file for that domain:

```
 $> cat /private/etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this working from other machines or locations? If this is working from other location then it may be some issue with your local ISP. If you recently changed DNS records then it can also be a DNS propagation issue. Sometimes, it takes 24 hours to propagate the DNS across the globe.

Comment: working from every other machine with the exception of my own. weve had the live `heroku` hosted domain up for a while now, probably nearing a month or so.